# I want to Pass data from component to js file(not in other component) in vue js. I am able to access it in component but not in js file

Tags: vue.js

I have one component Abc.vue, I want to emit event from here and listen it into js file not in other component, How can i do this?

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div>
      <input v-model="clickCount" placeholder="edit me" v-on:change="emitGlobalClickEvent()">
    </div>
    <TestWorld></TestWorld>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestWorld from '@/components/TestWorld.vue'
import {bus} from '../main'
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      message: 'test',
      clickCount: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitGlobalClickEvent () {
      bus.$emit('i-got-clicked', this.clickCount);

    }
  },
  components: {
    TestWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to listen this on abc.js file For that i am using below but not working while i am able to use in component

```
import { bus } from '../main'

bus.$on('i-got-clicked', clickCount => {
  console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${clickCount} clicks! :)`)
});
```

Comment: Show code for `bus` definition at `main`.

Comment: export const bus = new Vue()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the event hub pattern correctly, so your code works.

[**CodeSandbox Demo here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3n041pn36?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue).

Some points may be preventing you from seeing the listener (`$on`) working:

- The listener is declared in `abc.js`. Simply declaring it does not guarantee that it is executed. **Make sure `abc.js` is imported somewhere** so the code executes and the listener is properly registered.
- The `$emit` event code is triggered by a method that is on a `v-on:change`. For `<input>`s, the `change` event happens when the `input`s lose focus, not on typing. The event that happens char by char is `input` (or the `key*` events, naturally). So **type some text and focus out the `input`** to see the event triggered.
- If your question code is just a demo and the code that triggers the event is another `.js` file, make sure it executes **after** the `abc.js` does.

The [demo above](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3n041pn36?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue) handles these cases.

Comment: Thanks for your Solution!
But if i want to listen like  belowin abc.js , it thorws error(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined):-

export default {
   bus.$on('on-date-change', userinput => {
  console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${userinput} clicks! :)`)
})
}

Comment: Check the import. Probably it is importing bus from the wrong file.